# rule to remove "Public files directory Not fully protected" in nginx?

Tags: 7

I use D7 with nginx and php5-fpm on Linux and get this security warning:

> Public files directory Not fully protected

I see [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/97229/30527) that one needs to use this snippet in Apache's htaccess to resolve the issue:

```
# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</files>
```

Just wondering what should be the nginx equivalent rule?

**Update**: I already have this in my nginx configs:

```
root   /path/to/drupal;
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                return 404;
        }
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: I have this strange suspicion that Drupal may test for specific rules, not for their effect. Of course I;ll be glad to know if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .htaccess file won't have any effect in Nginx. You'll need to add your own rules to prevent PHP execution in the files directory.

e.g:

```
# Allow access to index.php only
location = /index.php {
  include fastcgi.conf;
  fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
}

# Any other attempt to access PHP files returns a 403.
location ~ \.php$ {
  return 403;
}
```

However, to fix that error message, you can actually just delete the old .htaccess file and Drupal will recreate a new correct one.

Note: the check is in [`system_requirements`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.install/function/system_requirements/7) with the line

```
if (!file_exists($htaccess_file) || !($contents = @file_get_contents($htaccess_file)) || strpos($contents, 'Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003') === FALSE) {
```

It only checks for that line, Drupal doesn't currently validate an actual PHP request to the relevant directory to test the handler.

Comment: So, was I right to guess that Drupal tests for the presence of `.htaccess`, not for the safety itself? :(

Comment: @David I have a more complicate rule. Just not sure if that suffice. Please see the updated question.

Comment: @Molot, indeed. It appears the check is in [`system_requirements`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.install/function/system_requirements/7) with the line `if (!file_exists($htaccess_file) || !($contents = @file_get_contents($htaccess_file)) || strpos($contents, 'Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003') === FALSE) {` It only checks for that line, Drupal could instead for example, create and request an arbitrary PHP file in the files directory to validate access.

Comment: Consider adding this to your answer - comment by @Godo shows it's confusing and people may expect that if config is OK, warning will disappear.

Comment: @Molot, I was not confused about role of .htaccess in nginx. I just wanted to make sure that my nginx configs is secure enough with respect to these vulnerabilities.

Comment: You can also use:   `location ~* ^/sites/default/files/(.+\.php)$ { return 403;  }`